# How can I make the texture transparent such that the plane is visible throught it?

Tags: three.js

Currently I do it with `opacity : 1` but it's not a good solution as the picture gets more and more dim. See the problem in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htz5p7fc/). I'd like to see the full width of the plane but it's shown in the bounds of sphere.

Comment: The opacity is applied to the plane in the fiddle so the picture does not change.. Have you tried to apply the transparency to the sphere ? If you want to see the whole plane you can also add a `depthTest:false` to its material. Tell if i miss something.

Comment: Hi, can you explain it a little bit more? I mean, you would like to see just the plane in the bottom and the rest of the texture as it is?

Comment: Atrahasis' answer sort of works. It shows the plane a little more but not all of it. I'd like to get the intersection point with this plane. See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htz5p7fc/15/). Intersections go up to z=5000 but the plane is not visible there...